# MDB 2003 VBA import Excel to mdb

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, format

Good afternoon, when I import Excel file to my MDB
this is the information appear on my excel file:
3/27/2020    37786    E-0724/20A    0000827    4    SERVICIOS ADMINISTRATIVOS INDUSTRIALES, S. DE R.L. DE C.V.    15540.94

The date appears format MM/DD/YYYY

when I imported to MDB appear the Date Format MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AMPM as sample

Date                            CTA    TRAFICO            PEDTO    CliNum    CLIENTE                                                                                             IMPORTE
3/27/2020    8:40:54 AM 37786    E-0724/20A    0000827    4            SERVICIOS ADMINISTRATIVOS INDUSTRIALES, S. DE R.L. DE C.V.    15540.94

but I need the format MM/DD/YYYY 
because when I used dlookup or .Seek I can't find the date

I am using the follow command:

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, _
             "CuentaMex", stDocName, True

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you, I appreciate your help and support.

Eng. Francisco Lara
Laredo ISD
Child Nutrition.

Comment: No idea why import is adding time part. Calculate a field in query that drops the time part and do your search on that field. Research DateValue() function. If you want to modify the saved value after import, run an UPDATE action SQL.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question(edit)! Hint: stored data may differ from displayed, as it may be formatted (click on cell to see real value!)! Sql criteria for a whole day, can be found easily.

Comment: Please go back to the Excel file, and right click to select the column having the date field e.g. 3/27/2020.  And for the column then select Format Cells... and select category DATE.  Scroll down the list choose 3/14/12 13:30  or some such, and press OK.  You should now be able to see the Full date 3/27/2020 8:40:54.  The full date has always been there, and Importing it to MDB did not add anything.  It is Excel that was not showing the full date.